# I am new to socket.io and websocket protocol. In the following code, why aren't there two separate socket connections?

Tags: react-hooks, websocket, socket.io

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.connect();
  console.log('useEffect callback invoked');
}, [])
```

In the code above, there're `console.log()` and `socket.connect()` functions. We know that when the component is first rendered, `useEffect` callback is invoked twice. Therefore, as a result, there're two logs. But the question is, if the callback is invoked twice, why aren't there two separate socket connections?

Comment: How did you know there are not two separate  socket connections?

Comment: Checked in the client with `socket.on("connect", () => console.log("new connection"))` and  with `io.on("connection", () => console.log("new connection"))` in the server